# Add a Key Pair to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently using a piece of code that I have found online for drawing a diagram by a set of angles and lengths, the problem I am having is constructing the array on the fly.

The array that works fine is this

```
arr = [
   { angle: 0, h: 100 },
   { angle: 45, h: 100 },
   { angle: 90, h: 300 },
   { angle: 135, h: 100 },
   { angle: 180, h: 100 }
];
```

but I am struggling with the syntax to insert the information into an array to match this format, here is what I have so far but this causes me an error which I am not sure.

```
for( var i = 1; i < 42;i++) {
arr[i].angle = document.getElementById("1m2mangle"+i).value;
arr[i].h = document.getElementById("1m2mlength"+i).value};
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, here is the code for drawing the lines from the input array.

```
ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
pos = getAngle(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, arr[i].angle, arr[i].h);
ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
```

Thanks

--Revised Function --

```
function draw<%response.write(counter1)%>() {
            var arr = [];

                for( var i = 1; i < 42;) {
                alert(document.getElementById("<%response.write(counter1)%>m2mangle"+i)).value);
                arr.push({
                        angle: document.getElementById("<%response.write(counter1)%>m2mangle1").value,  h: document.getElementById("<%response.write(counter1)%>m2mlength1").value});
                        i++;
                }

                var canvas = document.getElementById('curtainCanvas<%response.write(counter1)%>');
                if (canvas.getContext) {
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
                    var pos = { x: 15, y: 15 };
                    ctx.fillText(1,10,10);

                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

//                  alert(pos.x);
                        ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
                        pos = getAngle(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, arr[i].angle, arr[i].h);
                        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
                        ctx.fillText(i+2,pos.x, pos.y);
                    }

                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            }
```

Comment: "this causes me an error" — You didn't consider *telling us what the error is*?

Comment: What error does it cause? That `arr[i]` is undefined, because you forgot to define it as an object with `arr[i] = {};` before assigning properties to it? There’s an extra `}` in the third line.

Comment: Your loop is starting a `1`, remember arrays are zero based,..  So if you then did something like -> `for (a of arr) {` you would first get `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's done with JS:

```
for( var i = 1; i < 42;i++) {
  arr.push({
            angle: document.getElementById("1m2mangle"+i).value,
            h: document.getElementById("1m2mlength"+i).value
           });
}
```

WE're basically pushing a new object into the end of the array, which is the structure you need in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have checked the errors from this page now and it says that I am missing a semicolon but I can't find where and also getting an error that the function has not been declared but when I inspect the source it is showing fine.

I will post my full function code above.

Comment: remove the line with the alert, that should sort it out, however I'd strongly recommend you to attach your code as a snippet so that you'll be able to run it outside of your environment.

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem is, I am trying to append the "i" iterator to the end of the variable to create new field name for each of the fields on the page so they would read 1m2mangle1, 1m2mangle2, etc, if I hard code the field names it does the lookup fine.

Comment: If there any way that i can add an incrementing value to the end of the id so that it will iterate through all of the fields on the page as it will only return a single pair of fields from the start of the list as they all have the same id and i would like to refer to each of them as 1m2mangle1, 1m2mangle2, 1m2mangle3 etc.